# How do I add bullet points to a pdf document made with Zend_Pdf?

Tags: unicode, zend-pdf

I'm trying to add bullet points to a document I'm making with Zend_Pdf. I can't figure out how to get the actual bullet characters to show up. I know that the unicode for a bullet is 2022, but I have no idea how to actually convert that code to an actual bullet character. How should go about doing this?

EDIT: I should add that I've tried manually adding the bullet character by holding down ctrl+shift and typing "U2022". This puts a bullet in my code just fine. However, not only do the bullets not show up, the text on the line that follows the bullet doesn't show up either. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

*Bangs head against desk*

I didn't add the encoding parameter to $page->drawText() method.